# OpenCV--how to get better hand contour from low quality gray image?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, contour, binary-image

I need to get contour from hand image, usually I process image with 4 steps:

1. get raw RGB gray image from 3 channels to 1 channel:

   ```
   cvtColor(sourceGrayImage, sourceGrayImage, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
   ```
2. use Gaussian blur to filter gray image:

   ```
   GaussianBlur(sourceGrayImage, sourceGrayImage, Size(3,3), 0);
   ```
3. binary gray image, I split image by height, normally I split image to 6 images by its height, then each one I do threshold process:

   ```
   // we split source picture to binaryImageSectionCount(here it's 8) pieces by its height, 
   // then we for every piece, we do threshold, 
   // and at last we combine them agin to binaryImage        
   const binaryImageSectionCount = 8;
   void GetBinaryImage(Mat &grayImage, Mat &binaryImage)
   {
       // get every partial gray image's height
       int partImageHeight = grayImage.rows / binaryImageSectionCount;
       for (int i = 0; i < binaryImageSectionCount; i++)
       {
           Mat partialGrayImage;            
           Mat partialBinaryImage;
           Rect partialRect;
           if (i != binaryImageSectionCount - 1)
           {
               // if it's not last piece, Rect's height should be partImageHeight
               partialRect = Rect(0, i * partImageHeight, grayImage.cols, partImageHeight);
           }
           else
           {
               // if it's last piece, Rect's height should be (grayImage.rows - i  * partImageHeight)
               partialRect = Rect(0, i * partImageHeight, grayImage.cols, grayImage.rows - i  * partImageHeight);
           }

           Mat partialResource = grayImage(partialRect);    
           partialResource.copyTo(partialGrayImage);    
           threshold( partialGrayImage, partialBinaryImage, 0, 255, THRESH_OTSU);

           // combin partial binary image to one piece
           partialBinaryImage.copyTo(binaryImage(partialRect));

           ///*stringstream resultStrm;
           //resultStrm << "partial_" << (i + 1);
           //string string = resultStrm.str();

           //imshow(string, partialBinaryImage);
           //waitKey(0);*/
       }
       imshow("result binary image.", binaryImage);
       waitKey(0);
       return;
   }
   ```
4. use findcontour to get biggest area contour:

   ```
   vector<vector<Point> > contours;        
   findContours(binaryImage, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
   ```

normally it works well,
**But for some low quality gray image, it doesn't work,like below:**

[image: LowQualityGrayImage1]

[image: LowQualityGrayImage2]

the complete code is here:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


// we split source picture to binaryImageSectionCount(here it's 8) pieces by its height, 
// then we for every piece, we do threshold, 
// and at last we combine them agin to binaryImage        
const binaryImageSectionCount = 8;
void GetBinaryImage(Mat &grayImage, Mat &binaryImage)
{
    // get every partial gray image's height
    int partImageHeight = grayImage.rows / binaryImageSectionCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < binaryImageSectionCount; i++)
    {
        Mat partialGrayImage;            
        Mat partialBinaryImage;
        Rect partialRect;
        if (i != binaryImageSectionCount - 1)
        {
            // if it's not last piece, Rect's height should be partImageHeight
            partialRect = Rect(0, i * partImageHeight, grayImage.cols, partImageHeight);
        }
        else
        {
            // if it's last piece, Rect's height should be (grayImage.rows - i  * partImageHeight)
            partialRect = Rect(0, i * partImageHeight, grayImage.cols, grayImage.rows - i  * partImageHeight);
        }

        Mat partialResource = grayImage(partialRect);    
        partialResource.copyTo(partialGrayImage);    
        threshold( partialGrayImage, partialBinaryImage, 0, 255, THRESH_OTSU);

        // combin partial binary image to one piece
        partialBinaryImage.copyTo(binaryImage(partialRect));

        ///*stringstream resultStrm;
        //resultStrm << "partial_" << (i + 1);
        //string string = resultStrm.str();

        //imshow(string, partialBinaryImage);
        //waitKey(0);*/
    }
    imshow("result binary image.", binaryImage);
    waitKey(0);
    return;
}


int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    // get image path
    string imgPath("C:\\Users\\Alfred\\Desktop\\gray.bmp");     

    // read image
    Mat src = imread(imgPath);
    imshow("Source", src);        
    //medianBlur(src, src, 7);  
    cvtColor(src, src, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);     
    imshow("gray", src);    

    // do filter
    GaussianBlur(src, src, Size(3,3), 0);   

    // binary image
    Mat threshold_output(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0, 0, 0)); 
    GetBinaryImage(src, threshold_output);
    imshow("binaryImage", threshold_output);

    // get biggest contour
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;    
    findContours(threshold_output,contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    int biggestContourIndex = 0;
    int maxContourArea = -1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {       
        if (contourArea(contours[i]) > maxContourArea)
        {
            maxContourArea = contourArea(contours[i]);
            biggestContourIndex = i;
        }
    }

    // show biggest contour
    Mat biggestContour(threshold_output.rows, threshold_output.cols, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    drawContours(biggestContour, contours, biggestContourIndex, cv::Scalar(255,255,255), 2, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point());
    imshow("maxContour", biggestContour);
    waitKey(0);

}
```

could anybody please help me to get a better hand contour result?
thanks!!!

Comment: Before finding contour why don't you try some preprocessing methods to enhance the image and make the hand more clear?

Comment: but what kind of proprocessing should i try for these 2 image?Could you please give me some advice on it?

Comment: You could try contrast limited adaptive histogram equalization.

Comment: you can check the answer I've posted

Answer (score 1):

I have the code snippet in python, you can follow the same approach in C:

```
img = cv2.imread(x, 1)
cv2.imshow("img",img)

imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("gray",imgray)

#Code for histogram equalization
equ = cv2.equalizeHist(imgray)
cv2.imshow('equ', equ)

#Code for contrast limited adaptive histogram equalization
#clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=3.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
#cl2 = clahe.apply(imgray)
#cv2.imshow('clahe2', cl2)
```

This is the result I obtained:

[image]

If you're image is horribly bad you could try the code that I commented involving contrast limited adaptive histogram equalization.

Comment: Check these links for further info on the subject: [link 1](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html) and [link 2](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html)